# Generate a daily transaction Register

Tags: php, mysql

Please, i need assistance on how to generate a register for a transaction which is entered into the database daily as a register, group by each car. See my code below:

Selection Criteria:

```
<tr>
    <td>Start Date:<input type="date" name="d1" class="form-control" id="datepicker" /></td>
    <td>End Date:<input type="date" name="d2" class="form-control" id="datepicker" /></td>
    <?php $s = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tab_location");?>
    <td>Location:
        <select name="loc" class="form-control">
            <option>Select Location...</option>
            <?php while($lo = mysqli_fetch_array($s)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $lo['location_name'];?>"><?php echo $lo['location_name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>Action:<input type="submit" name="sbt" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Generate Report" /></td>
</tr>
```

Table to Display the result:

```
<table width="70%" border="0" style="margin-top:15px;" align="left" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S/N</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">FLT NO</th>
            <?php $list = array();
            $month = date('m');
            $year = date('Y');
            $dy = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,date('n'),date('Y')); 

            for($d=1; $d<=$dy; $d++) {
                $time = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);
                if (date('m', $time) == $month)
                    $list[]=date('Y-m-d', $time);
            }

            foreach ($list as $li){
                echo "<th>".$li."</th>";
            }?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if(isset($_POST['sbt'])){
            $loc = $_POST['loc'];
            $d1 = $_POST['d1'];  
            $d2 = $_POST['d2'];
            $c = 0;
            $st = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT(fltno),created_at,id,status FROM tab_ddaily WHERE loc='$loc' AND CAST(created_at as date) BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2' ORDER BY fltno");
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($st)){
                $c++;?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $c;?></td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $r['fltno'];?></td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $r['status']=='Available'?'<img src="includes/images/pass.jpe" width="20" height="10" />':'<img src="includes/images/wrong.jpe" width="20" height="10" />';?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
        } else {
            $loc = "";
            $d1 = "";
            $d2 = "";
        }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Above produces:[image]

I want it to produce:Distinct FLT No on a row with the status of each day  spreading from the 1st day to the last day of the month. Kindly help on how to achieve this. 
See structure and Data below:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). So sit back and relax... your server will be pwn3d soon enough and then you won't have to worry about this code anymore.

Comment: @MarcB: Pls, do you have any clue to this issue? If you do, pls let me know. If i know the solution, i will not post this question.

Comment: Please add your table structure and data in your question...

Comment: @d.coder: Table structure and data added. Pls note that it is truncated. I have date from 10th-15th for each FLT with status.

Comment: can you share sqlfiddle of this table quickly? Put good amount of data in it.

Comment: @d.coder : I have not use that before. How pls?

Comment: just need .sql file (table structure and data) of this table that you mentioned in screenshot.

Comment: @d.coder: so, i should add .sql of this table to my question, right?

Comment: yes you can add it here or you can use it in sqlfiddle and then share the URL in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123419/discussion-between-dave-and-d-coder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the output array returned from database and then reiterate it to show FLT and status date-wise.

```
<tbody>
<?php if(isset($_POST['sbt'])){
    $loc = $_POST['loc'];
    $d1 = $_POST['d1'];  
    $d2 = $_POST['d2'];
    $c = 1;
    $st = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT(fltno),created_at,id,status FROM tab_ddaily WHERE loc='$loc' AND CAST(created_at as date) BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2' ORDER BY fltno");

    $temp = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($st)){
        $temp[ $r['fltno'] ][ $r['created_at'] ] = array('id' => $r['id'], 'status' => $r['status']);
    }

    foreach($temp as $key => $values){
        $dates = array_keys($values); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $c;?></td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $key;?></td>
            <?php foreach ($list as $li){
                if(in_array($li, $dates)){ ?>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo ($values[$li]['status'] == 'Available') ? '<img src="includes/images/pass.jpe" width="20" height="10" />':'<img src="includes/images/wrong.jpe" width="20" height="10" />';?></td>
                <?php } else{ ?>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">n/a</td>
            <?php }
            } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php $c++;
    }
} else {
    $loc = "";
    $d1 = "";
    $d2 = "";
}?>
</tbody>
```

Outer loop is printing table row, SR_NO, FLT_NO and inner loop is printing status date wise.